# Object that can never be selected

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, outliner

[image]

I downloaded an object from Sketchfab and when I opened it, I encountered a situation like the image. I can't play on it at all. When I delete it, it completely removes the object. I think they are connected with Cube.002. Because when I delete one, the other is deleted as well. I would be very happy if you explain how this happens.

Comment: It's the same Object as the Above Cube.002, they are just in a different collection, the one below is inside Scene Collection and the one Above is inside Collection 1, if you move the above inside the Scene Collection you will see them appear as one single object. This Happens When you parent an object with a another object that is in a different collection (in this case, the Armature)

Comment: You can verify Emir's statement by checking two simple things: first of all, if you select the lower Cube.002 in the Outliner, the upper Cube.002 gets selected there as well as in the 3D Viewport. The second thing is, in Blender two objects of the same kind can never have the exact same name. So if one object is called Cube.002 and the other is called Cube.002, they have to be the same object.

Comment: I solved the problem when I tried on another file but thank you for your explanations 